# Vim colorscheme not appearing although successfully installed with vim-plug

Tags: vim

I have installed via `vim-plug` the `altercation/solarized` [colorscheme](https://github.com/altercation/solarized).

and here is my `~/.vimrc`

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'fatih/vim-go'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'
Plug 'altercation/solarized'

call plug#end()

syntax on


filetype indent plugin on

let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1

set background=dark

colorscheme solarized
```

However, when opening `vim`:

```
▶ vim ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /Users/pantelis/.vimrc:
line   20:
E185: Cannot find colour scheme 'solarized'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Any idea why the color scheme cannot be found?

**edit**: just for the record, here is the output of `PlugStatus`

[image]

Comment: Just in case: did you run `:PlugInstall` ?

Comment: yes, check my relevant edit to the question

Comment: As explained in the github repo, it seems you must install `altercation/vim-colors-solarized` instead of `altercation/solarized`, see the [README](https://github.com/altercation/solarized#fresh-code-on-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've installed `solarized8`, therefore, use:

```
colorscheme solarized8
```

`altercation/solarized` is not a vim script repo. Instead, it's the solarized color project repository, therefore Plug won't load the expected vim-script. i.e. solarized colorscheme isn't installed in your vim.

Comment: actually I have installed both; when I switch to `colorscheme solarized8` everything works (but I get the `solarized8` scheme)

Comment: `altercation/solarized` is not a vim script @pkaramol it's the solarized color project repo, therefore,  `altercation/solarized` won't install the vim colorscheme.

Comment: yep, turns out that was the case